# Drools: Casting to Array

Tags: java, arrays, drools

Got a quick question regarding casting an Object to Array. It doesn't seem to work for some reason. As you can see, i've first successfully casted to HashMap, that park is ok. However, the "value" part of the HashMap is suppoused to be an Array, so i tried to cast it in order to access the element inside of it. Like this:

```
((Array)((HashMap)$values1).get(p.getIdPatient()))[1] = 0;
```

This is the error i'm getting:

drools/spring/rules4/Rule_Possible_addicts_check1548290853.java (41:2032) : Array cannot be resolved to a type

So i'm new to Drools and my syntax is probably wrong, would appreciate if someone helped me successfully cast to Array. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, it's supposed to be `(Integer[])` instead of `(Array)`.